# autoscroll to empty but required q-input field in a form with validation Quasar 2.5.5 & Vuejs3

Tags: forms, scroll, vuejs3, quasar

I´ve a long form to fill out by the user with many required fields. So I used @submit.prevent,so that form can not be send if there are some missing  required fields. Also I´ve in the q-inputs  rules for the validations

If  required fields are missing the first one come an red focused but cause the form is so long, the user don´t see that, if he is in "the bottom" of the form - that isn´t user friendly :(

I want that if the user is clicked the submit Button and forgot to fill out some required field, that the app is scroll automatically to this field.

here are some code snippet - hope you can help me :(

```
<q-form class="q-gutter-md"
            @submit.prevent="save">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Angaben zum Auftraggeber</legend>
          <div class="q-gutter-sm">
            <q-input v-model="abrufauftrag.auftraggeber.organisationsname"
                     outlined
                     :readonly="!isEditable"
                     :rules="validierungsRules.rulePflichtfeldMitMax1024Zeichen"
                     label="Firma/Organisation *"/>
            <q-input v-model="abrufauftrag.auftraggeber.anschrift.strasse"
                     outlined
                     :readonly="!isEditable"
                     :rules="validierungsRules.rulePflichtfeldMitMax1024Zeichen"
                     label="Straße *"/>
            <q-input v-model="abrufauftrag.auftraggeber.anschrift.hausnummer" outlined
                     :readonly="!isEditable"
                     :rules="validierungsRules.rulePflichtfeldMitMax1024Zeichen"
                     label="Nr. *"/>
            <q-input v-model="abrufauftrag.auftraggeber.anschrift.land" outlined
                     :readonly="!isEditable"
                     :rules="validierungsRules.rulePflichtfeldMitMax1024Zeichen"
                     label="Land *"/>
            <q-input v-model="abrufauftrag.auftraggeber.anschrift.plz" outlined
                     :readonly="!isEditable"
                     :rules="validierungsRules.rulePflichtfeldMitMax1024Zeichen"
                     label="PLZ *"/>
            <q-input v-model="abrufauftrag.auftraggeber.anschrift.ort" outlined
                     :readonly="!isEditable"
                     :rules="validierungsRules.rulePflichtfeldMitMax1024Zeichen"
                     label="Ort *"/>
            <q-input v-model="abrufauftrag.auftraggeber.telefonnummer" outlined
                     :readonly="!isEditable"
                     :rules="validierungsRules.ruleTelNummer"
                     label="Telefon"/>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>


     <q-btn :loading="formSaved" color="primary" label="Speichern"
               title="Speichern"
               type="submit"
        >
          <template #loading>
        <q-spinner-dots/>
     </template>
  </q-btn>
```

Answer (score 4):

got it! :)

I used the @validation-error - Event from the Quasar QForm API to scroll to the invalid Element.

**`HTML:add @validation-error hook`**

```
    <q-form class="q-gutter-md"
                @submit.prevent="save"
                @validation-error="onValidationError">
    </q-form>
```

**`TypeScript: scroll to element`**

```
async function onValidationError(ref: any) {  
  const el = ref.getNativeElement()
  setVerticalScrollPosition(getScrollTarget(el), el.offsetTop, 1000)
}
```

Comment: For whose using JavaScript instead of TypeScript, use `ref.$el` instead `ref.getNativeElement()` and it should work fine)

Comment: Love ya!

make sure you import and deconstruct :

import { scroll } from 'quasar'
const { getScrollTarget, setVerticalScrollPosition } = scroll

source: 
https://quasar.dev/quasar-utils/scrolling-utils#scrolling-to-an-element

Answer (score 0):

You could use native [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) Web API method.

Here is a working example:

```
  <q-form
    @validation-error="
      (ref) =>
        ref.$el.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth',
          block: 'end',
          inline: 'nearest',
        })
    "
  >
```